# Mapping table to object dynamically in sqlalchemy

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I have to create multiple tables, all of which will have the exact same structure.
Using the below snippet I can create a python object and have it mapped to one of the tables. How can I have the _*tablename*_ field being provided at run time?
So like if I have 2 todo lists called TodayTodo, TomorrowToDo, what I want is if I could create an object of ToDoList type and somehow be able to provide it which table it needs to map to. How do I set the value of _*tablename*_ on my own?

```
class ToDoList(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'some_dynamic_string_here'
    id = Column(String, primary_key=True)
    title = Column(String)

    def __init__(self, id,title):
        self.id = id
        self.title = title
```

Comment: That's not how you design databases. What you call table name should be a fkey to a "higher level" table (concept).

Comment: But there are too many records in each table, I was thinking having different tables for each list would make sense. Putting it all together in 1 table and having a column to distiguish which list the todo should belong to - what advantage do you see in this design?

Comment: The big one is that you don't need DDL permissions to add a new list (in addition to normalization, code duplication, language and library support, etc.)